# How can I set up a password on Shipit.js

Tags: node.js, sudo, shipitjs

My deployment for shipit.js looks like this

```
// shipitfile.js
module.exports = shipit => {
  // Load shipit-deploy tasks
  require('shipit-deploy')(shipit)
  const backend_folder = 'backend';


  shipit.initConfig({
    default: {
      deployTo: '/var/www/app/',
      repositoryUrl: 'git@github.com:user/app.git',
    },
    staging: {
      servers: 'deploy@ip.ip.ip.ip',
    },
  })

  shipit.blTask('npm:install', async () => {
    await shipit.remote(`cd ${shipit.releasePath}/${backend_folder}/ && npm install --production`)
  })

  shipit.blTask('server:start', async () => {
    const be_command = 'NODE_ENV=production forever start build/server.js'
    await shipit.remote(`cd ${shipit.config.deployTo}/current/`
                        + `${backend_folder}/ && ${be_command}`)
  })

  shipit.blTask('server:restart', async () => {
    const command = 'forever restartall'
    await shipit.remote(`cd ${shipit.config.deployTo} && ${command}`)
  })

  shipit.on('updated', () => {
    shipit.start('npm:install')
  })

  shipit.on('published', () => {
    shipit.start('server:restart')
  })
}
```

When trying to clone from github, shipit fails because `deploy` needs to use sudo to create a folder. How can I give shipit `deploy`'s password so that it can sudo and create the folder?

Thank you.